# не работают медиа запросы! помогите найти ошибку, пожалуйста. Не работает позиционирование при ширине экрана от 568px до 800px

Tags: css, адаптивная-верстка, media-queries, экран

```css
.view {
    float: left;
    border: 10px solid #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #e6e6e6;
    cursor: default;
    background: #fff url(../images/bgimg.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  }
  
  .view .mask,
  .view {
    width: 302px;
    height: 187px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    top:0;
    left:0;
  
  }
  
  .iconss {
    height: 700px; 
    width: 700px; 
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  
  
  .view-one {
    top: 320px; 
    left: 180px;
  }
  
  @media screen and (min-width:568px) and (max-width:800px){
      .view-one {
          top: 320px;
          left: 0px;
      }
  }
  
  
  .view-two {
    top: 320px; 
    left: 520px;
  }
  
  @media screen and (min-width:568px) and (max-width:800px){
      .view-two {
          left: 360px;
      }
  }
  
  .view-three {
    top: 550px; 
    left: 180px;
  }
  
  @media screen and (min-width:568px) and (max-width:800px){
      .view-three {
          top: 320px;
          left: 0px;
      }
  }
  
  .view-four {
    top: 550px; 
    left: 520px;
  }
  
  @media screen and (min-width:568px) and (max-width:800px){
      .view-four {
          left: 360px;
      }
  }
  
  .view-five {
    top: 780px; 
    left: 180px;
  }
  
  @media screen and (min-width:568px) and (max-width:800px){
      .view-five {
          top: 320px;
          left: 0px;
      }
  }
  
  .view-six {
    top: 780px; 
    left: 520px;
  }
  
  @media screen and (min-width:568px) and (max-width:800px){
      .view-tenth .view-six {
          left: 360px;
      }
  }
  
  .view .eco,
  .view .thermo,
  .view .ivgb,
  .view .poritep,
  .view .ksz,
  .view .bonolit {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .view h2 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-family: Raleway, serif;
    padding: 10px;
    /*background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);*/
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
  }
  
  .view p {
    font-family: Merriweather, serif;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 14px;
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0px 20px 0px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .view .info,
  .view .info-i,
  .view .info-in,
  .view .info-inf,
  .view .info-info,
  .view .info-infoo {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 7px 14px;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Raleway, serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
  }
  
  .view a.info:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
  }
  
  
  /*3*/
  
  .view-tenth .eco,
  .view-tenth .thermo,
  .view-tenth .ivgb,
  .view-tenth .poritep,
  .view-tenth .ksz,
  .view-tenth .bonolit {
    transform: scaleY(1);
    transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
  }
  
  .view-tenth .mask {
    background-color: rgba(255, 231, 179, 0.3);
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  
  .view-tenth h2 {
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    background: transparent;
    margin: 20px 40px 0px 40px;
    transform: scale(0);
    color: #333;
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  
  .view-tenth p {
    color: #333;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0);
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
  
  }
  
  .view-tenth a.info {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0);
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
  }
  
  .view-tenth:hover .eco,
  .view-tenth:hover .thermo,
  .view-tenth:hover .ivgb,
  .view-tenth:hover .poritep,
  .view-tenth:hover .ksz,
  .view-tenth:hover .bonolit {
    -webkit-transform: scale(10);
    transform: scale(10);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  
  .view-tenth:hover .mask {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  
  .view-tenth:hover h2,
  .view-tenth:hover p,
  .view-tenth:hover a.info {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }

.eco {
    width: 300px;
    height: 185px;
    background-image: url(../images/posts/eco.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
} 

.thermo { 
    width: 300px;
    height: 185px;
    background-image: url(../images/posts/thermocube.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
}

.ivgb {
    width: 300px;
    height: 185px;
    background-image: url(../images/posts/ivgb.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
}

.poritep {
    width: 300px;
    height: 185px;
    background-image: url(../images/posts/poritep.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
}

.ksz {
    width: 300px;
    height: 185px;
    background-image: url(../images/posts/ksz.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
}

.bonolit {
    width: 300px;
    height: 185px;
    background-image: url(../images/posts/bonolit.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
}

.descr {
    padding-top: 30px; 
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.info {
    margin-left: 120px; 
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.descr-d {
    padding-top: 20px; 
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.descr-de {
    padding-top: 20px; 
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.descr-des {
    padding-top: 15px; 
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.descr-desc {
    padding-top: 15px; 
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.descr-descr {
    padding-top: 20px; 
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.info-i {
    margin-left: 120px; 
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.info-in {
    margin-left: 120px; 
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.info-inf {
    margin-left: 120px; 
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.info-info {
    margin-left: 120px; 
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.info-infoo {
    margin-left: 120px; 
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="iconss">
    <div class="view view-tenth view-one"><div class="eco"></div>
    <div class="mask">
    <p class="descr">Ярославский завод «ЭКО» основан в 2004 году. На сегодняшний день это активно развивающееся предприятие.</p>
    <a class="info" href="eco.html">ДАЛЕЕ</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="view view-tenth view-two"><div class="thermo"></div>
    <div class="mask">
    <p class="descr-d">Завод производит стеновые, перегородочные и U-образные блоки. Thermocube пользуется заслуженным уважением потребителей.</p>
    <a class="info-i" href="thermocube.html">ДАЛЕЕ</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="view view-tenth view-three"><div class="ivgb"></div>
    <div class="mask">
    <p class="descr-de">Основная сфера деятельности завода это производство газобетонных блоков автоклавного твердения .</p>
    <a class="info-in" href="ivgb.html">ДАЛЕЕ</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="view view-tenth view-four"><div class="poritep"></div>
    <div class="mask">
    <p class="descr-des">Завод PORITEP — это полностью автоматизированная линия, оснащенная современным высокопроизводительным оборудованием марки Wehrhahn.</p>
    <a class="info-inf" href="poritep.html">ДАЛЕЕ</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="view view-tenth view-five"><div class="ksz"></div>
    <div class="mask">
    <p class="descr-desc">ОАО «Костромской силикатный завод» - детище первой пятилетки - был основан 8 декабря 1930 года. Это один из старейших заводов Костромской области.</p>
    <a class="info-info" href="ksz.html">ДАЛЕЕ</a></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="view view-tenth view-six"><div class="bonolit"></div>
    <div class="mask">
    <p class="descr-descr">Bonolit Group – крупнейшая в России структура, объединяющая заводы лидеры по производству автоклавного газобетона на территории ЦФО.</p>
    <a class="info-info" href="bonolit.html">ДАЛЕЕ</a></div>
    </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Засуньте все стили в один медиа

Comment: т.е. медиа запросы сделать отдельным файлом???или как?не понятно что имеется ввиду. Расскажите, конкретнее, пожалуйста

Comment: ааааа....понятно....думаете заработает?

Comment: А вы попробуйте ;-)

Comment: я попробовала...(((((и ничего не работает. Почему же так???У вас работает??

Comment: Просто классы не верно указаны,например для .view-tenth .view-six надо .view-tenth.view-six или .view-six

Answer (score 0):

вот пример:

```
@media (max-width: 800px) and (min-width: 568px) {
```